# Should I do anything after formatting my computer because of malware infection?

Tags: windows-10, security, malware, spyware, trojan

Yesterday I realised that, after installing some software last weekend, Microsoft Defender was detecting several file on my Windows 10 document's temp folder. Some of them were deleted by the antivirus and some others simply disappeared before having time to delete them, but same or similar malware detection was found after just a few minutes. Malwarebytes confirmed the presence of some malware.

I quickly formatted my system, as I always have files in an external drive, so my computer is now as new (perhaps I have used a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but anyway a periodic resetting of Windows 10 is good).

**My question is**: Can some information have been exposed? Or the fact that Microsoft Defender was blocking those files (apparently trying to be executed in the background without my knowledge) avoided exposing information?

**The problem**: as I was so quick in format the computer, I don't know what malware exactly was detected (they were different malware detection, in files that didn't appear on Google, probably random names to the .exe files to avoid the malware detection though Windows Antivirus did its job).

**So the general question**: Should I take any special measures, perhaps with my passwords, bank accounts… or the fact that Windows Antivirus prevented the execution of malware is quite reasonable?

**Update:** My Instagram account has been compromised. Here is the [new question I have posted](https://superuser.com/questions/1645814/how-has-my-instagram-account-been-hacked) with the information I have about this attack.

Answer (score 1):

If in the few minutes of this episode you have not logged-in to any sensitive web-sites,
then your situation is "relatively" good.

It's unlikely but possible that the virus had time to access the
stored passwords on your browser, if you haven't used a secure
password vault such as LastPass.
This can be a bigger problem if you have reused the same passwords on
multiple websites.

In short, you are probably safe, but be on the lookout for unauthorized access.
I would counsel to change passwords on sensitive sites such as your bank,
facebook and email.

As you say that the hacker managed to avoid your 2-factor authentication,
the likely explanation is that he knows a bug in the website that allowed
that.

An unlikely but unfortunately feasible hack, is that the hacker got
enough information for faking your SIM. If you fear that possibility,
change your phone number.

Comment: As a final update, my Instagram account was hacked. What surprises me is that I had two factor authentication enabled. I could see a login from Turkey (I am from Spain), but somehow the hacker managed to avoid the 2 factor authentication. I have already changed all my passwords.